# Can't upgrade azure Postgres flexible server or add more vCores

Tags: postgresql, azure

I am trying to upgrade my postgreSQL server on azure from D2s_v3 to D4s_v3 but the options are not available as shown in the image below.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Sometimes  **scaling PostgreSQL Flexi Server will require a server restart**. It will only allow two-fold increments, and the main point is that it should not allow decreasing existing server storage.

In order to  **replica the same, created a new flexi server with D2s_v3**
configuration shown as below.
[image]

**Updated storage with D4s_v3**
[image]

[image]

**Verification:**
**Upon restart request change will be done.**

[image]